# Program :find Capital letter in word in python

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, uppercase

I have a challenge that find index of capital letter in word. For example "heLLo" : the output : [2,3]

```
def capital_indexes():
    word =input("enter your word :")
    s=list(word)
    a =[]
    print(s)
    for i in s:
        if (i.isupper()):
            a.append(s.index(i))
    print(a)

capital_indexes()
```

This program is works. But when i input a a word that first and second letter are capital and same, the output is [0,0].

Comment: The problem is that you are using s.index(i). Since both letters are the same, it will return the first index of the item. I’d suggest to use a separate variable out of the loop to keep track of the index that you are currently in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
def capital_indexes():
    word =input("enter your word :")
    a = []
    for i, j in enumerate(word):
        if (j.isupper()):
            a.append(i)
            print(j)
    print(a)

capital_indexes()
```

Output (with `heLLo` input):

```
L
L
[2, 3]
```

You can also condense this with list comprehension:

```
def capital_indexes():
    word =input("enter your word :")
    a = [i for i, j in enumerate(word) if j.isupper()]
    print(a)

capital_indexes()
```

Output (again with `heLLo` input):

```
[2, 3]
```

Comment: @MohsenZeraaty you can only accept one answer, the other answer is incorrect as it is just what you posted originally with different variable names